# How to print a line from its beginning?

Tags: c, file, text, line

I've been coding a program to write data into a text file and practice data processes in c, and find data from there, every data is stored as lines. There are lines, and data is stored line by line, such as:

**student name**     *student surname*     **student phone etc.**

When i take an input of "student name" it starts to print without printing the name itself, prints what comes after it, same happens if i search for surname, only phone will be printed out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *filePtr;
    filePtr=fopen("std.txt","r");
    char char_input[50];
    char string[500];


    printf("%s","Please give an input of the phone number\n");
        scanf("%s",char_input);

        while(!feof(filePtr)){
            fscanf(filePtr,"%s",string);
                if(strcmp(string, char_input)== 0){
                    fgets(string,500,filePtr);
                    puts(string);
            }
        }
    fclose(filePtr);
}
```

Text file:

```
Andrew Brooks 865 965 55
```

Input:

```
Andrew
```

Output:

```
Brooks 865 965 55
```

Desired output:

```
Andrew Brooks 865 965 55
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Also it can lead to problems using both `fscanf()` and `fgets()` to read the same file. Read the file line by line with `while(fgets(...) != NULL)` and apply `sscanf()` to extract each item from the string.

Comment: `puts(string);` ==> `printf("%s %s", char_input, string); /* string has embedded newline */`

Comment: @pmg that doesn't work the way i want, if i search from surname, it'll print surname and phone, but i wont get the name.

Comment: Right! Your current approach to the problem is ill-suited to your requirements. Try reading the file line-by-line with `fgets()` as per WeatherVane comment.

Comment: user9560064, Who or what text suggested `while(!feof(filePtr)){`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i don't remember tbh, i've seen it online while trying to google how to solve this problem i had, then people warned me here.

Comment: @user9560064 Then useful lesson today: "trying to google how to solve ...." is inherently a weak approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [incorrectly using `feof()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) and `fscanf(filePtr,"%s", ...` to incorrectly read a *line*.  Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of the file and convert to a *string*.

- Test the return value of `fgets()` to see if input occurred.
- Use `strstr()` to look for a matching sub-string within `string`.

Example:

```
    while (fgets(string, sizeof string, filePtr)) {
      if (strstr(string, char_input)){
        fputs(string, stdout);
      }
    }
```

Comment: i've tried using strcmp instead of strstr, why would that fail? it didn't work that way. but your comment solved the issue.

why did i write strcmp? bcs if i give an input of "andr" it'll give me info of "andrew" bcs its checking substring, while strcmp compares.

Comment: @user9560064 Note, a _line_ from the file is like `"Andrew Brooks 865 965 55\n"` and not `"Andrew Brooks 865 965 55"`.   With `scanf("%s",char_input);`, `char_input[]` will never contain a `'\n'`, thus `strcmp(string, char_input)` is never 0.

Answer (score 1):

The function `feof` will only tell you whether a previous input operation has already encountered end-of-file. It won't tell you whether you have now reached the end of file, so that the next input operation will fail. That function function is unable to predict whether the next input operation to `fscanf` or `fgets` will fail. Therefore, it should generally not be used as a loop condition. See this question for further information: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

In your case, `feof` may return false and the subsequent function call to `fscanf` may return `EOF` due to encountering end-of-file. In that case, your posted code will ignore the return value of `fscanf` and behave as if `fscanf` had succeeded, and your posted code will attempt to process the non-existant input. This is likely to result in a bug.

Therefore, instead of using the function `feof` to determine whether the loop should be continued, you should check the return value of the input function.

You could rewrite your loop like this:

```
while ( fscanf(filePtr,"%s",string) == 1 ) {
    if ( strcmp(string, char_input ) == 0 ) {
        fgets( string, 500, filePtr );
        puts( string );
    }
}
```

This will solve the problem mentioned above of not checking the return value of `fscanf`. However, depending on the exact input, it may also be possible that the function `fgets` will fail due to encountering end-of-file. Therefore, it would be better if your program also checked the return value of the function `fgets`, instead of simply assuming that the function succeeded.

Another problem is that the line

```
puts(string);
```

will only print the contents of `string`, which is `" Brooks 865 965 55"`. However, you also want to print `"Andrew"`, which was read by the `fscanf` function call but has been meanwhile overwritten by the `fgets` function call. The simplest solution would be to print it before it gets overwritten. However, this will not work if the user searches for `"Brooks"` instead of `"Andrew"`, because the word `"Andrew"` will already have been discarded in the previous loop iteration. This is because calling `fscanf(filePtr,"%s",string)` in a loop will not read one line of input per loop iteration, but will instead read a single word per loop iteration (which is not very meaningful).

Another consequence of reading in the input file word by word using `fscanf(filePtr,"%s",string)` is that your won't be able to find a match for the phone number `"865 965 55"`. This is because your program will first read `"865"` from the input file and determine that this "word" is not identical to the search string. It will then read `"965"` and determine the same thing. It will do the same for `"55"`.

The best solution would probably be to redesign your loop so that it always reads exactly one line of input per loop iteration, instead of only one word per loop iteration. After reading in one line of input, you can then parse the line by splitting it into "first name", "last name" and "phone number" using the function [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *filePtr;
    char search_string[50];
    char line[200];

    //open input file
    filePtr = fopen( "std.txt", "r" );
    if ( filePtr == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to open input file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter search string: " );

    //Note that the following code now uses "fgets" instead
    //of "fscanf", because fscanf will only read a single
    //word, when using the "%s" format specifier. This means
    //that it would be unable to read the phone number
    //"865 965 55" as an input string, because that line
    //consists of three "words".

    //read exactly one line of input from user
    if ( fgets( search_string, sizeof search_string, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remove newline character from input line by
    //replacing it with terminating null character
    search_string[strcspn(search_string,"\n")] = '\0';

    //read exactly one line of input from the input file
    //per loop iteration
    while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, filePtr ) != NULL )
    {
        char first_name[50];
        char last_name[50];
        char phone_number[50];

        //attempt to parse input
        if (
            sscanf(
                line,
                "%49s %49s %49[^\n]",
                first_name,
                last_name,
                phone_number
            )
            != 3
        )
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "WARNING: skipping line due to parse error!\n"
            );

            continue;
        }

        //parsing was successful, so we can now search the
        //3 individual fields for the search string
        if (
            strcmp( search_string, first_name   ) == 0
            ||
            strcmp( search_string, last_name    ) == 0
            ||
            strcmp( search_string, phone_number ) == 0
        )
        {
            //remove newline character from input line by
            //replacing it with terminating null character
            line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = '\0';

            //print entire input line of file for user
            printf( "%s\n", line );
        }
    }

    //cleanup
    fclose(filePtr);
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter search string: Andrew
Andrew Brooks 865 965 55
```

```
Please enter search string: Brooks
Andrew Brooks 865 965 55
```

```
Please enter search string: 865 965 55
Andrew Brooks 865 965 55
```

Note that the code above is not perfect, as it has the following issues:

1. When using `fgets`, if the input line is too long to fit in the buffer, then the program will not detect this, although it should probably print an error message and quit, in such a situation.
2. If any of the fields "first name", "last name" or "phone number" is larger than 49 characters, the code does prevent a buffer overflow (which would possibly cause your program to crash), but it still doesn't handle this situation properly, for example by checking for such a situation and by printing an appropriate error message.

However, for your purposes, the code should probably be sufficient.

A more robust program, which fixes these issues, would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//This function will read exactly one line of input using
//fgets and verify that the line was not too long for the
//input buffer. Note that the buffer size must be two bytes
//longer than the actual string length, because there must
//be space for the newline character and the terminating
//null character. The newline character will be overwritten
//with another terminating null character.
//On success, it will return true. If not further input is
//available due to end-of-file, it will return false.
//Otherwise, the function will not return, but will
//terminate the program with an error message.
bool get_one_line_of_user_input( char *buffer, int buffer_size )
{
    char *p;

    if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        if ( feof( stdin ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //No newline character was found. This could mean
        //that the line was too long to store in the input
        //buffer, in which case, the program should quit
        //with an error message. However, it could also mean
        //that input has been redirected to come from a
        //file, and that this file ends with a line without
        //a line ending. In that case, the missing newline
        //character can be ignored.
        if ( !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "line too long for buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove newline character
        *p = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *filePtr;
    char search_string[50];
    char line[200];

    //open input file
    filePtr = fopen( "std.txt", "r" );
    if ( filePtr == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to open input file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Please enter search string: " );

    //read exactly one line of input from user
    if ( !get_one_line_of_user_input( search_string, sizeof search_string ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input failure!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //read exactly one line of input from the input file
    //per loop iteration
    while ( get_one_line_of_user_input( line, sizeof line ) )
    {
        char first_name[50];
        char last_name[50];
        char phone_number[50];

        //attempt to parse input
        if (
            sscanf(
                line,
                "%49s %49s %49[^\n]",
                first_name,
                last_name,
                phone_number
            )
            != 3
        )
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "WARNING: skipping line due to parse error!\n"
            );

            continue;
        }

        //verify that none of the fields was too long
        if (
            strlen( first_name   ) == 49
            ||
            strlen( last_name    ) == 49
            ||
            strlen( phone_number ) == 49
        )
        {
            //At least one buffer is full, and we have no way
            //to determine whether the limit was exceeded or whether
            //we are merely at the limit, so we must assume that
            //the limit was exceeded.
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "WARNING: skipping line due to field length "
                "limit exceeded!\n"
            );

            continue;
        }

        //parsing was successful, so we can now search the
        //3 individual fields for the search string
        if (
            strcmp( search_string, first_name   ) == 0
            ||
            strcmp( search_string, last_name    ) == 0
            ||
            strcmp( search_string, phone_number ) == 0
        )
        {
            //print entire input line of file for user
            printf( "%s\n", line );
        }
    }

    //cleanup
    fclose(filePtr);
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(filePtr,"%s",string)` without a _width_ should be avoided.

Comment: @chux: I agree. However, in that code snippet, I simply took over that function call from OP's original code and moved it inside the `while` loop condition. I didn't want to make any other changes such as code improvements, because that would have distracted from the point that I was making (which was to check the return value of `fscanf`). Later, in the code of the actual program, I do limit the width in my call to `sscanf`.